# APNS-php push is so slow

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I am doing a project that makes use of apns-php to push notifications to users of an apple app.

There are about 2.7 million users. Currently, it takes about 3 days to push so many users. I allow 1000 concurrent processes for ApnsPHP Server. It is eating up almost all my server memory.

Is this speed for apns push normal? or there is someway that I can speed up?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to queue the push operations? Another fact is that you can use a single connection to send multiple messages.
Several answers mention these kind of solutions here in SO too.